# Wrong time when I convert UTC time to "E. South America Standard Time"

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, timezone

I created this method to convert a DateTime from UTC to another timezone

```
public static DateTime GetDateTimeFromUtcTo(string timeZoneName, DateTime time)
{
    DateTime newDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(time, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

    TimeZoneInfo newTzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);

    bool isDaylight = newTzi.IsDaylightSavingTime(time);

    TimeZoneInfo gmtTzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    if (!gmtTzi.Equals(newTzi))
    {
        newDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(newDateTime, gmtTzi, newTzi);
    }

    if (isDaylight)
    {
        newDateTime = newDateTime.AddHours(1);
    }

    return newDateTime;
}
```

This method does not work properly when `timeZoneName` = "E. South America Standard Time" (--03:00 GMT) and  `time` = "16/05/2013 20:00:00" (UTC time).

The correct datetime must be "16/05/2013 17:00:00", but i get "16/05/2013 16:00:00". Why?

Comment: This looks more like a problem regarding "daylight savings" which not consistently used in that timezone... which is a really complicated matter... Brazil comes to mind (see http://www.timetemperature.com/samerica/south_america_time_zones.shtml)

Comment: Using DateTimeKind.Unspecified is a bad idea.  Get ahead by being explicit that this is a UTC timestamp and using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc().  Which produces 17:00 on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-thinking it.  You simply need:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);
DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(time, tz);
```

You can pass `"E. South America Standard Time"` for the `timeZoneName` without issue.

You don't need to switch the kind first.  Either `Utc` or `Unspecified` incoming kinds will work.  If you are passing a `Local` kind, then you are doing something wrong and you will get an exception.  See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx).

You also do not need to look up UTC/GMT, or check for DST manually.  That is all done internally.

Comment: When using Linux this might not work, make sure you take a look at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/cross-platform-time-zones-with-net-core/
and https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter (Thanks Matt for the OSS code)